# Iterate over copy types

Tags: iterator, rust

It is clear that iterators pass around a references to avoid `moving` objects into iterator or it's closure argument, but what with Copy types? Let me show you a small snippet:

```
fn is_odd(x: &&i32) -> bool { *x & 1 == 1 }
// [1] fn is_odd(x: &i32) -> bool { x & 1 == 1 }
// [2] fn is_odd(x: i32) -> bool { x & 1 == 1 }

fn main() {
    let xs = &[ 10, 20, 13, 14 ];

    for x in xs.iter().filter(is_odd) { 
        assert_eq!(13, *x);                     
    }   

    // [1] ...is slightly better, but not ideal
    // for x in xs.iter().cloned().filter(is_odd) { 
    //     assert_eq!(13, x); 
    // }
}
```

Am I right that `.cloned()` is preferred when we iterate over something like `&[i32]` or `&[u8]`, where extra indirection is involved instead of just copying the tiny data unit?

But it looks like I can not avoid references passed into `is_odd` function.

Is there a way to make `[2]` function from above snippet work for higher-level functions like `filter`?

Assume that I understand that moving non-Copy type into `predicate` function is silly. But not all types use `move` semantics by default, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It is clear that iterators pass around a references

This blanket statement is not true, iterators are more than capable of yielding a non-reference. `filter` will provide a reference to the closure because it doesn't want to give ownership of the item to the closure. In your example, your iterated value is a `&i32`, and then `filter` provides a `&&i32`.

> Is there a way to make [2] function from above snippet work for higher-level functions like filter?

Certainly, just provide a closure that does the dereferencing:

```
fn is_odd(x: i32) -> bool { x & 1 == 1 }

fn main() {
    let xs = &[ 10, 20, 13, 14 ];

    for x in xs.iter().filter(|&&x| is_odd(x)) { 
        assert_eq!(13, *x);                     
    }   
}
```

Comment: I should be more precise in questions..
The thing I was looking for is a alternative to filter which moves values into closure and, in case of copy values, passes an copy (or maybe it should be bounded to Copy trait). I am not sure it is a worthwhile to write my own filter iterator (because it seems like && is idiomatic even for primitives; I am still thinking just copying them around is better).

Comment: @IskanderSharipov it's tough to tell if a `filter_copy` method would be useful, but that's what profiling is for! I'd encourage you to write it and time it to see if it makes you code faster. For myself, I trust in the optimizer enough to believe, without proof, that it would actually optimize to the same speed.